# jQuery Promise each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I am creating a UserScript that will generate a list of URLs to a users photo gallery. A user gallery may have multiple pages, each page has multiple thumbnails that have a link to a page which contains the full-sized image url.

I am using jQuery to request the pages though I'm not getting the desired results when a user gallery only contains 1 page. I get some results when a user gallery contains multiple pages but I only get 1 page worth of results.

```
var userID = 0;

function getUserID() {
    var query = window.location.search;
    var regex = /UserID=(\d+)/;
    var regexResult = query.match(regex);
    if (regexResult !== null) {
        return regexResult[0].replace('UserID=', '');
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

function getGallery(userID) {
    function getGalleryPage(userID, page, gallery) {
        var data = {};
        if(page > 0) {
            data = { btnNext: ">", PageNo: page };
        }

        var url = 'http://www.domain.com/' + userID;

        return $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: data,
            dataType: 'html'
        }).then(function(result){
            $result = $(result);
            $result.find('form[name="frmGallery"]').find('img').each(function() {
                var url = ''
                // Do stuff to get url

                getGalleryImage(url).done(function(imageLink) {
                    gallery.push(imageLink);
                });
            });

            $btnNext = $result.find('input[name="btnNext"]');
            if($btnNext.length > 0) {
                page += 1;
                return getGalleryPage(userID, page, gallery);
            } else {
                return(gallery);
            }
        });
    }
    return getGalleryPage(userID, 0, []);
}

function getGalleryImage(url) {
    return $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: url,
        dataType: 'html'
    }).then(function(result){
        var imageUrl = '';
        // Do stuff to get full sized image url
        return imageUrl;
    });
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    userID = getUserID();
    if(userID === 0)
        return;

    getGallery(userID).done(function(gallery) {
        $.each(gallery, function(index, value) {
            console.log(value);
        });
    });
});
```

I think this part of my script is not correct:

```
$result.find('form[name="frmGallery"]').find('img').each(function() {
                var url = ''
                // Do stuff to get url

                getGalleryImage(url).done(function(imageLink) {
                    gallery.push(imageLink);
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written, there's no attempt to aggregate the inner promises returned by `getGalleryImage()`.

You need to map the delivered img elements to an array of promises and aggregate them with `jQuery.when()`.

I would write it something like this :

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var userID;

    function getUserID() {
        var query = window.location.search;
        var regex = /UserID=(\d+)/;
        var regexResult = query.match(regex);
        if (regexResult !== null) {
            return regexResult[0].replace('UserID=', '');
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    function getGallery(userID) {
        var gallery = [];
        var page = 0;
        var url = 'http://www.domain.com/' + userID;
        function getGalleryPage() {
            var data = (page > 0) ? { btnNext: ">", PageNo: page } : {};
            return $.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                url: url,
                data: data,
                dataType: 'html'
            }).then(function(result) {
                $result = $(result);

                //map jQuery collection of img elements to Array of promises
                var promises = $result.find('form[name="frmGallery"]').find('img').map(function(imgElement, i) {
                    var url = ''
                    // Do stuff to get url
                    return getGalleryImage(url);
                }).get();// .get() is necessary to unwrap jQuery and return Array

                //aggregate promises
                return $.when.apply(null, promises).then(function() {
                    //accumulate results
                    gallery = gallery.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
                    // recurse/terminate
                    if($result.find('input[name="btnNext"]').length > 0) {
                        page += 1;
                        return getGalleryPage();
                    } else {
                        return gallery;
                    }
                });
            });
        }
        return getGalleryPage();
    }

    function getGalleryImage(url) {
        return $.ajax({
            method: 'GET',
            url: url,
            dataType: 'html'
        }).then(function(result) {
            var imageUrl = '';
            // Do stuff to get full sized image url
            return imageUrl;
        });
    }

    userID = getUserID();
    if(userID !== 0) {
        getGallery(userID).then(function(gallery) {
            $.each(gallery, function(index, value) {
                console.log(value);
            });
        });
    }
});
```

You should also impose a limit on the number of recursions, just in case one day some userID yields thousands of pages.